# Inequation for a function and its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I am reviewing my analysis stuff and i am really unsure how to prove this.

Given a normed space $Y$ and a differentiable function $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow Y$, show that

$$ ||f(1)-f(0)|| \leq ||f´||_\infty $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ell:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous linear functional on $Y$. Then consider $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(t)=\ell\left(f(t)\right)$. Observe that
\begin{equation*}g'(t)=\lim_{h\to0}\ell\left(\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\right)=\ell\left(f'(t)\right)
\end{equation*}
and so by mean value theorem we have
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert \ell\left(f(1)-f(0)\right)\right\rvert=\left\lvert\ell\left(f'(c)\right)\right\rvert
\end{equation*}
for $0<c<1$. The result follows from Hahn-Banach by choosing $\ell$ so that $\left\lvert\left\lvert \ell\right\rvert\right\rvert\le1$ and $\ell\left(f(1)-f(0)\right)=\left\lvert\left\lvert f(1)-f(0)\right\rvert\right\rvert$ and bounding $\left\lvert\left\lvert f'(c)\right\rvert\right\rvert$ by $\left\lvert\left\lvert f\right\rvert\right\rvert_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left(\left\lvert\left\lvert f'(t)\right\rvert\right\rvert\right)$.

Comment: I didnt know Hahn-Bach until now but that looks very nice. Thank you

Comment: Glad to spread knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), there is some $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$\frac{\|f(1)-f(0)\|}{1-0}\leqslant\bigl\|f'(c)\bigr\|(\iff\|f(1)-f(0)\|\leqslant\bigl\|f'(c)\bigr\|).$$So, $\|f(1)-f(0)\|\leqslant\|f'\|_\infty$.

Comment: I thought about that aswell but i was unsure because i was working with norms. I tried to show that from $||f(1)-f(0)|| \geq c $ it already follows that $||f´||_\infty \geq c$